# Need help Phonegap failed build on android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm still learning building android apps using phonegap, I have this error when compile my app in terminal:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library /Users/name/Workspace/phonegap/myApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/android/CordovaLib/unspecified/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

Can someone help me to solve this problem. This error just came out when I'm compiling android not iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a fairly recent version of Cordova and trying to build for a really old version of Android. As the error message clearly states, the Android SDK version you are targeting is `7` while the lowest Android SDK version supported by the Cordova version you are using is `10`. Change that config and it should work.

You need to set the Android SDK minimum version to a suitable value (a.k.a a value greater than or equal to 10) using the `android-minSdkVersion` preference.

More information : http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_preferences.md.html#_android_only

Note : Since this error is related to Android SDK version this would not affect iOS builds.

Comment: @kodokbuncit Added some more information. Please read about the Cordova preference as well as the Android config.

Comment: its work @brahmana i just change <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" /> to <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" /> and it's work. thanks alot